# Magento admin page login problem at first time after installation

Tags: magento2, admin, login

When I install Magento 2, first of all, its screen was blank, when I resolve that problem then I am unable to login to admin page, I give my name and password again and again but its give me error "You did not sign incorrectly or your account is temporarily disabled." and show some other admin and password
[image]

Please help me resolve this problem,
and also in code of validator it show me some error like
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Run below command in terminal and change admin user name and pass.

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --admin-email="your_email_address" --admin-firstname="your_firstname" --admin-lastname="your_lastname"
```

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean

And now check with

username: admin

password: admin123

After done update your username and password as per you want.

Comment: Could not open input file: bin/magento sir it giving me this error in cmd screen

Comment: You have to run this command: "php bin/magento cache:clean" from your project root directory.

Comment: can u guide me4

Comment: First of all did you run first command? for change your username and password ?

Comment: that problem is solve ,,now another one arrise,,,magento dnt show me icon images

Comment: Okay, now check I have updated my answer few of command I have added. You have run it step by step.

Comment: can u tell me plz ,where is root folder alocated

Comment: /var/www/html/magento   this magento is your root folder

Answer (score 0):

I have read the answer of Ravi and your comments. I cannot add comment so I will post this answer.

Make sure you have done these things in order to make the view works properly:

1. Make sure there's a `.htaccess` file inside `/pub/static` folder.
2. Set permission of `/pub/static` folder to writable permission (0777). Go to your Magento root folder then type this command: `chmod -R 0777 pub/static`
3. Deploy your view: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
4. Press `Ctrl + F5` on the Magento page in your browser to refresh the page view.

Hope this helps!

Comment: where is magento root folder

Comment: Where do you install your magento website? The magento root folder is the folder contain `index.php` and `.htaccess` file.It's the base directory of magento website.

Comment: then how i can run command on this

Comment: can you tell me where to run these command

Comment: If you using Windows, let access your magento server's SSH using Putty, then go to the magento root folder and run all the commands above. If you get error permission message with `bin/magento` command, try this command `chmod a+x bin/magento` to solve that problem.

Comment: After you have deployed the static content successfully, a `deployed_version.txt` file will appear in `/pub/static` folder.